# Enforce Excel template formatting for all the cells

Tags: excel

Please let me know if there is a way to enforce cell formatting in Excel workbook.

Basically I have a workbook(template) that I will distribute to my users. My Users then will fill the template with the data and send it back to me. But when the users do the copy and paste from another excel sheet or from other source, the numbers fields are getting automatically converted to number format by Excel. I dont want that. I want to enforce all the fields as text. I cannot add data validation rule because, I dont want to add extra effort to my users to correct the data validation errors.

What I want in this case is that - Excel to keep everything as text and dont add any formatting by its own and also keep the destination formatting no matter what the source formatting is.

Excel versions that I support are greater than Office 2007 format i.e., xlsx files

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to lock formatting, but a possible option is to allow the users to enter their numbers in the spreadsheet (e.g. in the `A` column) and then have a formula in a hidden column which converts it to plain text (something like `=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1))` and drag down). Does that work?

Comment: As I said, I don't want my users to take the extra effort of adding the formula and dragging it down for the whole entries. Even if I add the formula and distribute the template(I don't know if this is possible but assuming it is), my users will still have to drag down for all the rows(the number of rows is huge i.e., more than 1lakh). Moreover they can enter numerical values in multiple columns. So i think it is not feasible.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. *You* will be managing the formula, not the users. The dragging down of the formula occurs by *you*, before you send out the template. The fact that the users can enter numerical values in multiple columns is no problem, that just means you need multiple formulas (e.g. `= MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)` and `= MID(B1,1,LEN(B1))`). If you edit your question to show some sample data, I can show you what I mean.